# Jenkins pipeline groovy project job list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jobs

I want to list all jobs of my current project within my groovy pipeline script.
Does someone know how to do that? With

```
env.BRANCH_NAME
```

I am just getting my current branch.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a multibranch pipeline? Thats the common way to list all branches of a project

Answer (score 0):

you can get it from jenkins api, for example the URL:

```
http://jenkinsHost:8080/job/jobName/api/json?pretty=true&tree=jobs[name]
```

will produce something like:

```
 {
  "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject",
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
      "name" : "develop"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
      "name" : "master"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
      "name" : "testing"
    }
  ]
}
```

and then you can parse the branches names with groovy. (In the above case, "develop", "master" and "testing" are branches)